# How to add Choice Add-PnpField that uses term store meta data for the choices?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

How can I change my code below so that I am using the term store data for my choices when adding a new pnp field?

I have tried googling for an answer but no luck! Any help is much appreciated <3

```
# ADD NEW FIELD
$30 = Add-PnPField `
        -DisplayName 'Player Position' `
        -InternalName PlayerPosition `
        -Type MultiChoice `
        -Choices "Striker","Defender","Midfielder","Goally" `
        -Group 'Football Content Types' `
        -Required       

# CREATE TERM GROUP
$1 = New-PnPTermGroup `
   -GroupName "Football" `
   -Description "Football Term Group"

# CREATE TERM SET
$2 = New-PnPTermSet `
  -Name "Defender" `
  -TermGroup "Football" `
  -lcid "1033"

# CREATE TERM
$3 = New-PnPTerm `
  -TermSet "Defender" `
  -TermGroup "Football" `
  -Name "Center-back" `
  -lcid "1033"
```

Comment: Try this - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnptaxonomyfield?view=sharepoint-ps

Comment: Got it working thank you!

Comment: Please post ur resolution in answer section so that it will be helpful for others too